# Recommendations for aggregating MySQL data (millions of rows)

Tags: mysql, aggregate

Can anyone recommend a strategy for aggregating raw 'click' and 'impression' data stored in a MySQL table with over 100,000,000 rows?

Here is the table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `clicks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `companyid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `contextid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `period` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `location` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ip` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `useragent` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `companyid` (`companyid`),
  KEY `period` (`period`),
  KEY `contextid` (`contextid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=21189 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What I want to do is make this data easier to work with. I want to extract weekly and monthly aggregates from it, grouped by type, companyid and contextid.

Ideally, I'd like to take this data off the production server, aggregate it and then merge it back.

I'm really in a bit of a pickle and wondered whether anyone had any good starting points or strategies for actually aggregating the data so that it can be queried quickly using MySQL. I do not require 'real time' reporting for this data.

I've tried batch PHP scripts in the past but this seemed quite slow.

Comment: I've seen this be implemented in routines that run during the night and populate tables with monthly and weekly aggregated data. Maybe that is an option on your case. Obviously in this case the performance was not considered as a critic point as the system was not used during the night.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - Any recommendations regarding implementation? Language?

Comment: Well, i experienced two ways of doing this. The first was scheduling oracle jobs that executed stored procedures that did all we needed to be done, it worked like a charm and was pretty easy because the RDBMS handled everything. The second is implementing PHP script that was executed via cron job on the server sending a GET parameter to be more secure. Don't really know your possibilities.

Comment: Certainly PHP is a possibility. I guess pure PHP without a framework would be best for performance.

Comment: Exactly, a simple PHP script with the aggregation logic only would be ideal.

Comment: You could also execute PHP from the cron job without going throug the web server. After all, there is a command line interface version of PHP. @Mt.Schneiders, looks like your comments would stand a good chance of getting accepted if you were to turn them into an answer.

Comment: @MvG, Thanks, i wrote the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a simple PHP script with the whole monthly/weekly data aggregation logic and make it execute via cron job at a given time. Depending on the software context, it could possibly be scheduled for running at night. Additionally, you could pass a GET parameter in the request for recognizing the request source.

Comment: I would be careful with this however, keep in mind that there are limits to the amount you can store in memory when aggregating data.  With a hundred million records this definitely can be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in MySQL replication... set up a 2nd server who's sole job is just to run the reports on the replicated copy of the data set, and therefore you can tune it specifically for that job. If you set up your replication scheme as master-master, then when the report server updates it's own tables based the report findings, those database changes will automatically replicate back over to the production server.

Also I would highly recommend you read [High Performance MySQL, 3rd Ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449314287), and take a look at http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/ for further info on working with massive datasets in MySQL